# automate the mirroring from bitbucket to google cloud repo when a repo is created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-cloud-repository

I have multiple repos mirrored from bitbucket to Google Cloud source repo. I'm trying to find a way to automate the process for doing this since right now I have to do it every time manually. Since I am working with multiple people who create repos almost daily, it's annoying to check every day if there is a new repo created that needs to be mirrored. Is there any way to achieve this?